# How can I hear music through my notebook speakers when the earphones are plugged in

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, skype, speakers

I have HP folio 13-1020us with original windows 7.

When the earphones are plugged in. music played on the web goes to the earphones. I want it to go to the speakers. I know its possible because when skype receives a message its beep cause the music to play over the speakers (when the earphones are plugged it).

Ideally only skype calls would route to the headphones while music and other audio will go to the speakers.

The computer has dolby advanced audio panel on it.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Try setting the default audio device to your speakers and change Skype's "output device" to the headphones http://www.virtualaudiostreaming.net/images/Windows7-audio-device-setting-applet.PNG

Comment: Thanks ! I only have speakers and headphones device. No seperate device for speakers like in your screenshot.